# Inspect elements of td onclick?

Tags: jquery, html-table

[DEMO][1] I want to inspect the elements of td onclick button , but the button should not be counted as a element of table.

`html code`:

```
<table id="inspect">
<tr>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>
        <input type="button" class="click"></input>
    </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

`jquery`

```
$("#inspect").click(function () {
    alert('total rows -' + $this.parents('tr').find('td').length);
});
```

Comment: Why have you not posted you code at SO? This is not expected from a user having decent reputation

Comment: Please post your code here, and explain what you want to achieve. You want to "inspect elements", but not have the button "counted". Do you want a count? The list of elements as an array of objects? Or something else completely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to  do following changes:

1) Apply `.click()` on the button not the table

2) Use `.closest()` instead of `.parent()` since your button is placed inside a `td`

```
$(".click").click(function () {
    alert('total rows -' + $(this).closest('tr').find('td').length);
});
```

---

Based on your comment, you can use `.map()`

```
$(".click").click(function () {
    var currentTd = $(this).parent();
    var tdStr = $(this).closest('tr').find('td').not(currentTd).map(function() {
       return $(this).text(); 
    }).get().join(',');

    alert(tdStr);
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tAGmb/3/)**

Comment: i don't want length i want the elements this-> `12,13,14,15,16`

Comment: thanks got it..But i want to save each element in different variable so if i go to the next page i can see that saved values. is that possible

Comment: You need a form to submit the value. It's beyond the scope of this question. I'd suggest you to ask a new question :-)

Comment: i want the data from table to submit how it is possible?

Comment: Your question required another answer which I'd suggest you to close this question and ask a new one with relevant code which is easier for people to help you.

Answer (score 1):

you could simply deduct it by 1 as there is no other buttons with td:

```
$(".click").click(function () {
    alert('total rows -' + $(this).closest('tr').find('td').length - 1);
});
```